# Caching Go build in Github runner

Tags: docker, go, caching, github-actions, buildx

I am trying to wrap my head around how I could possibly keep the Go modules and build cache between action runs, the catch (no pun intended :) ) being that the actual build is performed inside a Docker container.

What my setup looks like:

- Github self-hosted runner (running on Kubernetes, using actions-runner-controller - I can use both ephemeral and non-ephemeral runners, so this is not a restriction)
- The build itself is performed inside a Docker container - something like this:

```
FROM golang:1.21-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN go mod download -x
RUN go build -o output/result -v ./mycode

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=builder /code/output/result /myprogram
CMD ["myprogram"]
```

Now since the code uses quite a lot of modules, downloading and building all the components takes a while. I am trying to find a way to keep GOCACHE and GOMODCACHE between runs, to save on build time. And I just cannot seem to find that way.

What I have tried:

- using `RUN --mount=type=cache` for the `download`/`build` commands. But the problem now becomes "how do I keep those cache layer between buildkit setups?"
- using registry cache or GHA cache on the `build-push-action`. But this only seems to cache image layers, and the Docker cache is quickly invalidated by the `COPY` in  the Dockerfile
- using [buildkit-cache-dance](https://github.com/reproducible-containers/buildkit-cache-dance) - but it crashes when I attempt to use it within an actions runner controller runner. And even when it does not, I still was not able to find a way to truly persist the GOCACHE/GOMODCACHE directories between runs

So I came here for help - is there a way I can accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Some additional info:

- Yes, I know that the recommendation is to always start with a clean environment when building (the ARC documentation goes out of its way to make this very clear :) ). And I will do that for the final build. But in the test environment, the build times really begin to add up...
- This might be a lot easier if I just built the binary directly on the runner, and not in a Docker container. But this is not something I can change easily at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can split mod downloads into separate layers that can be cached by docker (because each instruction in this Dockerfile translates to a layer in your final image).

like this:

```
WORKDIR /code

COPY ./go.mod ./
COPY ./go.sum ./
    
# Download dependencies
RUN \
    go version && \
    go mod download

COPY . .
```

Comment: Thank you. That does help, but it only shaves about 1/3 of the build time - actually building all those modules on every run still takes a while. :(

Comment: yeah of course compiling takes time)

Comment: Vadov - well, yes. But I am trying my best to limit [sword fights](https://xkcd.com/303/) :) . And I know Go can do that - on a local machine, using the cache, compiling the code takes less than 30 seconds. I just wish that Go had a way of doing things in two steps: "compile all the imported modules", and "compile my code". This way, the first step would go into the Docker layer cache, and everyone would be happy...

Comment: @Bogd you can also try command `RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod/ go build -o output/result -v ./mycode` instead of `RUN go build -o output/result -v ./mycode`. Cache mounts let you specify a persistent package cache to be used during builds

Comment: thank you. I did try that (see the details in the original post). But the problem is that I have yet another "layer of non-persistence" :) - how do I keep those cache layers between runs? There seems to be no easy way of pushing the cache layer to GHA, for example (and, as I mentioned, buildkit-cache-dance didn't help either)